# Prevent Moving Mouse / Pressing Key on Keyboard from stopping Windows from Locking

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse, screensaver

I currently have my computer set to go to screensaver and lock the workstation after 10 minutes. Everything works fine but if someone is near the computer and it is about to lock, you see the screen flash blank for a second and you can quickly move the mouse or press something on the keyboard to keep it from locking.

At a workplace that I currently go to, they were able to get rid of that from happening some how. I can only assume it is through a program that is running in the background (based on the checkbox isn't checked to lock the workstation in the screensaver options dialog) but I don't want to assume without asking. Is there anything I can do to prevent anyone from pressing a key or moving the mouse and stopping the computer from locking without a background application locking the computer? I have tried no screen saver but still having the computer lock but the same thing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Disable the screen saver grace period

> There is a delay between the time that the screen saver locks the computer and the time that the password protection is established. During this interval, you can use a key press or mouse movement to unlock the computer without having to type the password.
>
> <sub>Source: [Screen saver grace period bypasses password protection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/221784/en-us)</sub>

The `ScreenSaverGracePeriod` registry entry determines the delay in seconds; when it's missing the delay defaults to `5` seconds. Setting it to `0` enforces an immediate lock.

1. Open a command prompt as administrator.
2. Type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
    reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "ScreenSaverGracePeriod" /t REG_SZ /d 0 /f
   ```

   Changes are applied immediately.

## References

- [Screen saver grace period bypasses password protection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/221784/en-us)